# Trying to return only part of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT SPEAKERNAME, 
       SUBSTR(SPEAKERADDRESS, CHARINDEX('-', SPEAKERADDRESS), 4)
  FROM SPEAKER;
```

I am tyrying to only return the postcode from `SPEAKERADDRESS` and the postcode is always after '-' but i am getting an invalid identifier (ORA-00904) error for CHARINDEX

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF51178) did you find `charindex()`?

Comment: can you add sample data for that and expected o/p

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `CHARINDEX`, use `INSTR` instead: http://www.sqlines.com/oracle/functions/instr

Comment: 2113 and the addresses are all of different lengths but this is always 4 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`:

```
SELECT SPEAKERNAME, 
       SUBSTR(SPEAKERADDRESS, instr(SPEAKERADDRESS, '-')+1 ,4)
  FROM SPEAKER;
```

Check [Demo](http://rextester.com/KGE50755).